# How to modify JSON values in file using json.hpp

Tags: c++, json, fstream, jsonparser

I am using the following library to work with JSON stuff : https://github.com/nlohmann/json

I have a json configuration file, and some of the contents in it are as follows:

```
 "mqtt_config": {
        "host": "my_mqtt_broker.com",
        "password": "admin",
        "port": 8883,
        "tls": true,
        "username": "admin"
    }
```

I would like to be able to change any of these values from within my C/C++ application.

What i'm doing is as follows for example on attempt to change the port number :

```
std::ifstream in(configFile);
json infile = json::parse(in);

infile["mqtt_config.port"] = 1883;

std::ofstream out(configFile);
out << std::setw(4) << infile << std::endl;

in.close();
out.close();
```

However this doesn't behave as I would expect and it simply adds `"mqtt_config.port": 1883` as a separate line in the file and not nested as I would expect? Would anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you have misunderstood the API, `infile["mqtt_config.port"] = 1883;` this statement will add a key with string `mqtt_config.port`

It can be fixed by

```cpp
infile["mqtt_config"]["port"] = 1883;
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Kbj7jKGz5)